# Need to find the repeating integers and their count in a java array

Tags: java

I am using the below code but the output is not correct

//1,3,4,5,6,3,2,4,6,7,9,4,12,3,4,6,8,9,7,6,43,2,4,7,7,5,2,1,3,4,6,311,1

```
    public static void repeat(){

        int count[] = new int[]{1,3,4,5,6,3,2,4,6,7,9,4,12,3,4,6,8,9,7,6,43,2,4,7,7,5,2,1,3,4,6,311,1};
        int [] done ;
        for(int i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {

            int a = count[i] ;
            int counter=0;  
            int j=i+1;

            //System.out.println(a+"--"+""+j);
            for(j=i+1 ; j < count.length; j++){
                if (a == count[j]) {        
                     counter=counter+1;
            }
                System.out.println(a+" is appearing --"+""+counter +" times");
            }

        }   

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a Map with key type of Integer and value of same type. Then iterate through count array - check if given value exists in map - if not add it as key with value 1. If it does exist then just increase the value by 1.

After this go through the map and get all keys with value > 1.

```
 public static void repeat(){

    int count[] = new int[]    {1,3,4,5,6,3,2,4,6,7,9,4,12,3,4,6,8,9,7,6,43,2,4,7,7,5,2,1,3,4,6,311,1};

    Map<Integer,Integer> repetitionCount = new HashMap<>();

    for(Integer i : count) {
       if(repetitionCount.containsKey(i)) {
           Integer prevValue = repetitionCount.get(i);
           repetitionCount.put(i,prevValue+1);
       } else {
           repetitionCount.put(i,1);
       }
    }

    repetitionCount.forEach((key,value) -> {
            if(value>1) {
                System.out.println("Repetition of " + key + " - " + value + " times");
            }
        }
    );

}
```